# Series expansion of complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that $e^z= \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k}$.

I took the taylor series $f(z)=\displaystyle \sum_k \frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!}(z-z_0)^k$ centered at $z_0=0$ and obtained $$e^z= \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{0}(z-0)^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!},$$

is that all I need to do? Seems a bit too simple... the only thing I can think of is that we need to show that the series also converges. Would I just write out the real and imaginary parts of $e^z$ as series expansions (i.e. if $z=x+iy$ in terms of $e^x$,$\sin y$ and $\cos y$) and then note that those individual series converge?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654369/power-series-for-complex-exponential?rq=1).

Comment: what is your definition of $e^z$?

Comment: @Mattos Thanks I'll take a look

Comment: @zhw Same as everyone elses: $e^x( \cos y + i \sin y)$

Comment: proving that $e^z$ is equal to its Taylor series is not so easy, you need to prove first some (complex) analysis theorems. or, you can prove that $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ (with $x$ real) is a solution of $f'(x) = f(x)$ and how $f(0) = 1$ it proves that $f(x) = e^x$ (defined as $e^{\log(x)} = x$ with $\log x = \int_{1}^x \frac{dt}{t}$

Comment: That is not the same as everyone else's. It's often defined as the series you're trying to derive.